# Can Spring MVC or Spring Boot work with Amazon Alexa?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to develop a small Alexa skill with Spring Boot and Spring MVC framework via https (I tried both of them). 
However when I tried to add alexa-skill-kit maven dependency in pom.xml. I got so many different kinds of errors.
like 'servlet.init() error','can't create a child container' etc. 
It seems like the newest version of Alexa Java SDK has some conflicts with my spring set up...
Is there anyone who has set up amazon alexa with spring successfully? 
Or a 'Hello world' sample project shared in github?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've developed a alexa skill using spring boot successfully. Here's the dependency definition from my pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazon.alexa</groupId>
    <artifactId>alexa-skills-kit</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Hopefully that clears up your issues.

Also to use the sdks message objects you can add the bean

```
@Bean
Module speechletRequestModule() {
    return new SpeechletRequestModule();
}
```

and then a request mapping in your rest controller is simply

```
@RequestMapping(value = "skills/myskill", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public SpeechletResponseEnvelope handle(@RequestBody final SpeechletRequestEnvelope speechletRequestEnvelope) {}
```

Comment: Thanks! I found developing in Python is much easier with Flask-Ask. The Alexa Java SDK has many duplicated imports. Did you also config the speechletservlet with @configration?

Comment: I actually didn't use their provided servlet and used spring controller instead w/ request/response body returning the jackson mapped objects they provide in the sdk. I also used their signature/timestamp/etc verifiers just hooked into spring @ControllerAdvice configs and what not. Also just too add, by going down this route I was easily able to add google endpoints into the same app and have it support both platforms with minimal work.

Comment: @StephenGarlick can you share some sample application. I am also trying to do the same for a week but it's not working